# swi_prolog calling c++ program

Tags: c++, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a c++ program and I would like to have a prolog program call functions or methods in the c++ program.  I am new to this and if there is some tutorial I would appreciate the link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the SWI documentation:

- [C interface](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%279.4%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/foreigninclude.html%27%29%29)
- [C++ interface](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/pl2cpp.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I have been reading the documentation at the swi_prolog site as well as other sites.  I am looking for a basic sample project so that I may learn how to set up the files, libraries, etc.